# Reputation - Feedback

Tags: feature-request, comments, reputation

The user can comment in some answers or questions only if there is enough reputation. Is there any constant reputation for comments? or It differs based on question and user?

Feedback: It will be good if there is no reputation for commenting at least,

Answer (score 2):

You need 50 reputation to post comments freely.  The question or user doesn't matter, other than the reputation requirement.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges for this reputation threshold, and for others.

The reputation requirement is there to ward off spammers and nonsense comments from users who don't have a vested interest in the site.

Comment: I read "don't have a vested interest in life". I might be biased.

Answer (score 1):

It is a privilege earned at 50 rep.

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege. You can see all the privileges you can earn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

We require 50 rep for this to ensure bots and spammers can't comment.